# Grails GORM how to load existing remote DB tables in my application

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I need to use some tables from a MySQL database which is not mine. I can connect to the database remotely (with known host, db name, user, password). I know the structure of the database but I don't want to create new tables, modify a structure of existing tables etc.

The only thing I want to do is to load records (rows) from this DB in my application and modify its column values or add a new row...

Can you give me some advice please? How to set it in my grails 2.4.3 application?

Comment: What is the new DB you'll be loading into?  You will want to export to a csv file (or something similar) from your mySQL db and simply import into whatever DBMS you will be using.  I don't think you need anything Grails specific for this other than creating domain classes to map to your db tables.

Comment: It is the same DB. I don't need any migration. I just need to provide simple CRUD operation with this DB. You talk about domain classes - it is true but how can I set a datasource in my application. I use GORM with Hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new Groovy sql instance like below

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
...
final Sql sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<db-name>",
                <user>, 
                <password>, 
                "org.postgresql.Driver")
sql.eachRow( 'select * from tableName' ) { println "$it.id -- ${it.firstName} --" }
```

Detailed info can be seen here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL

You could add mysql/oracle details instead of postgres.